What is the meaning of "rayon" in Gounod's "Magali's Song" (Mireille)?
What is the meaning of "rayon" in this construction:

MIREILLE
C'est en vain que tu me crois prise;
Je suis nuage!
VINCENT
Et moi, la brise,
Je t'emporte dans un rayon!
MIREILLE
Je suis le bluet qui sommeille
Dans un sillon…
[ La brise est douce et parfumée, Chanson de Magali, ds. Mireille (Charles Gounod) ]


Given the source of the quote, couldn't the rayon be a sunbeam?

@PeterShor Yeah, or just a "ray", maintaining some level of indetermination.

No specific "construction" here. You should consider the word was chosen for the rhyme (and number of syllables) rather than the meaning. The quote is unusual enough to make us think of  Gounod's opera Mireille (9th century, so not that "old"!)  Rhyming with sillon & papillon, in a pastoral setting, not a wide range of words to chose from, so as Peter Shor says "sunbeam" is likely, just as "ray of light". But other meanings of rayon  connected with nature could be imagined, it's poetry.

@Judith I believe it means "I am the breeze & carry you[the cloud] away along a sunbeam. If the rhyming of rayon and sillon results in an untranslatable pun, it would be lost in most French-speaking audiences.

I don't see that the actions "L'oiseleur te prendra", "Je suis nuage", and "Je t'emporte sur un rayon" have to take place at night. These are hypothetical actions, so they're not constrained to take place in real time. And furthermore, bird-catchers and bees generally don't work at night.
